# R: ggplot2 density plot shows wrong fill colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, fill

I would like to plot densities of two variables ("red_variable", "green_variable") from two independent dataframes on one density plot, using red and green color for the two variables.

This is my attempt at coding:

```
library(ggplot2)

### Create dataframes
red_dataframe <- data.frame(red_variable = c(10,11,12,13,14))
green_dataframe <- data.frame(green_variable = c(6,7,8,9,10))
mean(red_dataframe$red_variable) # mean is 12
mean(green_dataframe$green_variable) # mean is 8

### Set colors
red_color= "#FF0000"
green_color= "#008000"

### Trying to plot densities with correct colors and correct legend entries
ggplot() +
geom_density(aes(x=red_variable, fill = red_color, alpha=0.5), data=red_dataframe) + 
geom_density(aes(x=green_variable, fill = green_color, alpha=0.5), data=green_dataframe) +
scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Density of red_variable", "Density of green_variable"), values = c(red_color, green_color)) +
xlab("X value") +
ylab("Density") +
labs(fill = "Legend") +
guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

Result: The legend shows correct colors, but the colors on the plot are wrong: The "red" variable is plotted with green color, the "green" variable with red color. The "green" density (mean=8) should appear left and the "red" density (mean=12) on the right on the x-axis. This behavior of the plot doesn't make any sense to me.

I can in fact get the desired result by switching red and green in the code:

```
### load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

### Create dataframes
red_dataframe <- data.frame(red_variable = c(10,11,12,13,14))
green_dataframe <- data.frame(green_variable = c(6,7,8,9,10))
mean(red_dataframe$red_variable) # mean is 12
mean(green_dataframe$green_variable) # mean is 8

### Set colors
red_color= "#FF0000"
green_color= "#008000"

### Trying to plot densities with correct colors and correct legend entries
ggplot() +
geom_density(aes(x=red_variable, fill = green_color, alpha=0.5), data=red_dataframe) + 
geom_density(aes(x=green_variable, fill = red_color, alpha=0.5), data=green_dataframe) +
scale_fill_manual(labels = c("Density of red_variable", "Density of green_variable"), values = c(red_color, green_color)) +
xlab("X value") +
ylab("Density") +
labs(fill = "Legend") +
guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

... While the plot makes sense now, the code doesn't. I cannot really trust code doing the opposite of what I would expect it to do. What's the problem here? Am I color blind?

Answer (score 2):

On your code, in order to have color at the right position, you need to specify `fill = red_color` or `fill = green_color` (as well as alpha as it is a constant - as pointed out by @Gregor) outside of the `aes` such as:

```r
...+ 
geom_density(aes(x=red_variable), alpha=0.5, fill = red_color, data=red_dataframe) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=green_variable), alpha=0.5, fill = green_color, data=green_dataframe) + ...
```

Alternatively, you can bind your dataframes together, reshape them into a longer format (much more appropriate to `ggplot`) and then add color column that you can use with `scale_fill_identity` function (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_identity.html):

```r
df <- cbind(red_dataframe,green_dataframe)

library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% pivot_longer(.,cols = c(red_variable,green_variable), names_to = "var",values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(Color = ifelse(grepl("red",var),red_color,green_color))

ggplot(df, aes(val, fill = Color))+
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5)+
  scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", name = "Legend", labels = levels(as.factor(df$var)))+
  xlab("X value") +
  ylab("Density")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Many thanks @dc37. I could reproduce the plot above. Unfortunately, if the two original dataframes have different lengths, they cannot be glued together with cbind(). Any solution on how to deal with different lengths of the two dataframes?

Comment: You're welcome! If your two dataframes have not the same length, but the same number of columns, you can add a column on each that will stipulate if it is the red or green variable and then use `rbind` instead of `cbind`. And like that, you are bypassing the use of `pivot_longer`. Does it make sense ?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use `ggplot` as if it's base graphics... the mindset shift can take a little while to get used to. dc37's answer shows how you should do it. I'll try to explain what goes wrong in your attempt:

When you put `fill = green_color` inside `aes()`, *because it's inside `aes()`* `ggplot` essentially creates a new column of data filled with the `green_color` values in your `green_data_frame`, i.e., `"#008000", "#008000", "#008000", ...`. Ditto for the red color values in the red data frame. We can see this if we modify your plot by simply deleting your `scale`:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = red_variable, fill = green_color, alpha = 0.5), data =
                 red_dataframe) +
  geom_density(aes(x = green_variable, fill = red_color, alpha = 0.5), data =
                 green_dataframe) +
  xlab("X value") +
  ylab("Density") +
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

[image]

We can actually get what you want by putting the `identity` scale, which is designed for the (common in `base`, rare in `ggplot2`) case where you actually put color values in the data.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = red_variable, fill = green_color, alpha = 0.5), data =
                 red_dataframe) +
  geom_density(aes(x = green_variable, fill = red_color, alpha = 0.5), data =
                 green_dataframe) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  xlab("X value") +
  ylab("Density") +
  labs(fill = "Legend") +
  guides(alpha = FALSE)
```

[image]

When you added your `scale_fill_manual`, ggplot was like "okay, cool, you want to specify colors and labels". But you were thinking in the order that you added the layers to the plot (much like base graphics), whereas `ggplot` was thinking of these newly created variables `"#FF0000"` and `"#008000"`, which it ordered *alphabetically* by default (just as if they were `factor` or `character` columns in a data frame). And since you happened to add the layers in reverse alphabetical order, it was switched.

dc37's answer shows a couple better methods. With `ggplot` you should (a) work with a single, long-format data frame whenever possible (b) don't put constants inside `aes()` (constant color, constant alpha, etc.), (c) set colors in a `scale_fill_*` or `scale_color_*` function when they're not constant.

Comment: Thanks! Things seem more delicate than I thought.

Comment: One data frame in long form is hard to mess up - that's what ggplot is designed for, and that's why the best practice is to get your data in the right shape before plotting. My answer is all about how you can make hacky workarounds...